# Increase performance for multiple REST requests

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, webrequest, servicenow

I am new to REST and VSTO's. I made my first excel add-in that does a web request and puts the information into excel. The users specify what tickets they want by putting them in a column on excel. The add-inthen does a webrequest to get the information based on what is in that column. Then it writes that info into excel.

The problem is the API i am contacting only allows you to send one ticket at a time. The problem is it is slow. It freezes for about 3 seconds then takes about 1.5 seconds per entry. I step through my project and the bulk of the time is making the webrequest. Can anyone suggest better alternatives to my code?

Where I do all the work.

```
public partial class RibbonMain
{
    private void RibbonMain_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    //Gather Incident list
    //collect incident information
    //write the results to excel
    private void btnGetServiceNowInfo_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        //Get active worksheet
        ProgressForm progressForm = new ProgressForm();
        progressForm.Show();
        Excel.Worksheet activeWorksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.GetActiveWorksheet();
        int intRow = 2;
        rClient rClient = new rClient();
        rClient.httpUsername = Settings.Default["Username"].ToString();
        rClient.httpPassword = Settings.Default["Password"].ToString();
        string strReponse = string.Empty;

        //iterate through incident row
        //adds incident numbers to list
        while (true)
        {
            Range intRange = activeWorksheet.get_Range("D" + intRow);
            if (intRange.Value == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            Range numRange = activeWorksheet.get_Range("A" + intRow);
            Range descRange = activeWorksheet.get_Range("B" + intRow);
            Range sys_idRange = activeWorksheet.get_Range("C" + intRow);
            rClient.endPoint = "https://dev32395.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_query=number%3D" + intRange.Value + "&sysparm_fields=number%2Csys_id%2Cdescription&sysparm_limit=1";
            strReponse = rClient.makeReqest();
            var deserializedResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResult>(strReponse);
            var jsonResult = deserializedResult.result.First();
            numRange.Value = jsonResult.number;
            descRange.Value = jsonResult.description;
            sys_idRange.Value = jsonResult.sys_id;
            intRow++;
        }
        lstIncidentNum.Clear();
        progressForm.Hide();
    }

    //call settings form
    private void btnSettings_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        SettingForm settingForm = new SettingForm();
        settingForm.Show();
    }
}
```

This line `using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())`is where it take 2000 MS for the first request and around 300 MS for other requests.

```
public enum httpVerb
    {
        GET,
        POST,
        PUT,
        DELETE
    }

    class rClient
    {
        public string endPoint { get; set; }
        public httpVerb httpMethod { get; set; }
        public string httpUsername { get; set; }
        public string httpPassword { get; set; }

        public rClient()
        {
            endPoint = string.Empty;
            httpMethod = httpVerb.GET;
            httpUsername = string.Empty;
            httpPassword = string.Empty;
        }

        public string makeReqest()
        {
            string strResponseValue = string.Empty;

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);

            webRequest.Method = httpMethod.ToString();

            string Credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(httpUsername + ":" + httpPassword));

            webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Credentials);

            using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                if(webResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Error: " + webResponse.StatusCode.ToString());
                }

                using(Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            strResponseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return strResponseValue;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the Tasks namespace to generate multiple simultaneous calls but all you might end up doing it overloading your web server. Its worth an experiment to see if its the communication lag causing slow client-side responses or whether its your web server acting slowly. To do this you might install the free tool Fiddler to watch the call/response pattern from your Excel client to the web server - it will give you an idea where the time is being spent. If its network lag then generating multiple simultaneous calls will help make the total time less.

Comment: I will look into it, and servicenow is cloud based so don't know if I will overload them or not. Surely not.